# How to change the initial value of a nested field to zero instead of null value.?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, serialization

How to change the initial value of a nested field to zero instead of null value.?

In my case **Prize** model is a **OneToOneField** to model **Album**

**Serializer**

```
class PrizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Prize
        fields = ['title', 'amount']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prize = PrizeSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'prize']
```

Some items have prize data but some do not have prize data. If there is no prize data it will be shown as **null**,

```
>>> serializer.data
{
    "album_name": "The Grey Album",
    "artist": "Danger Mouse",
    "prize": null
}
```

how to change this **null** value to zero.?

**Expected output**

```
>>> serializer.data
{
    "album_name": "The Grey Album",
    "artist": "Danger Mouse",
    "prize": "0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SerializerMethodField` on your `AlbumSerializer`, something like this:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prize = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_prize(self, instance):
        if hasattr(instance, 'prize'):
            return PrizeSerializer(instance.prize).data
         return "0.0"

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'prize']
```